# Android: how to know the webview load finish if it load the redirect page of more time?

Tags: url, redirect, webview

1. a webview
2. a redirect url
3. webview load redirect url
4. webview how to know the redirect url load finish?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this approach..

```
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl(yourUrl);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            dialog.hide();
        }
    });
```